# How to set size results CSE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-custom-search

I'm use CSE (google custom search) to display results, but it display default 10 results, I wanna display by control number of results, ex display 4 results. Here is my code.

```
 function gcseCallback() {
    // key to search
    var key = $("#txtkeyword").val();
    if (document.readyState != 'complete')
        return google.setOnLoadCallback(gcseCallback, true);
    google.search.cse.element.render({ webSearchResultSetSize: 'small', gname: 'gsearch', div: 'google-search', tag: 'searchresults-only', attributes: { linkTarget: '_blank' } });
    var element = google.search.cse.element.getElement('gsearch');
    element.execute(key);
};
(function () {
    var cx = 'xxxxx:xxxx';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script'); gcse.type = 'text/javascript'; gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https' ? 'https:' : 'https:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.google.com/cse/search/advanced

Websearch Restricts --> Result Size (0 - 20)